# Footer Moving with Bigger Screens

Tags: html, css, footer

I am having an issue with my footer.

It looks great on normal screen sizes, tablets and phones but for people who have larger screens/resolutions the footer is going all the way to the left.

View screen shot here for a big screen: http://www.bkd.com/images/bkd-big-screen.png

This is the actual page URL: http://www.bkd.com/new-test-2.htm

I am needing the footer to stay lined up with the experience BKD logo at the top. Here is it on a normal sized screen how i would like it across the board: http://www.bkd.com/images/bkd-normal-screen.png

Here is the coding for the footer:

```
   <div id="footer3">

   <div id="footer3-contents">
   <div class="span-6">
   <a href="https://www.facebook.com/BKDcpasandadvisors?ref=ts"><img width="23" height="25 alt="BKD Facebook" src="/images/icons/social-media/facebook-icon.png"></a>
   <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/bkd-cpas-&-advisors?trk=biz-companies-cym"><img width="25" height="25" alt="BKD LinkedIn" src="/images/icons/social-media/linkedin-icon.png" id="icons"></a>
   <a href="https://twitter.com/bkdllp"><img width="25" height="25" alt="BKD Twitter" src="/images/icons/social-media/twitter-icon.png" id="icons"></a>

   <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/experienceBKD"><img width="25" height="25" alt="BKD Youtube"src="/images/icons/social-media/youtube-icon.png" id="icons"></a>
  <a href="https://plus.google.com/+BkdCPAsandadvisors/posts"><img width="25" height="25" alt="BKD Google Plus" src="/images/icons/social-media/google-icon.png"></a>



   </div>
   <div id="footer-legal" class="span-18 last">

   <ul>
   <li><a href="/contact-us/">Contact Us</a></li>
   <li><a href="/about-us/terms-of-use.htm">Terms of Use</a></li>
   <li> <a href="/about-us/privacy-policy.htm">Privacy Policy</a></li>
   <li> <a href="/about-us/disclosures.htm">Disclosures</a></li>
   <li> <a href="http://ultipro.bkd.com/">UltiPro</a></li>
   <li style="color:#fff">Copyright © 2014 BKD, LLP.</li>


   </ul>
   <a href="/about-us/praxity/"><img src="/images/praxity-white.png" width="101" height="47"></a>
   </div><div class="clear"></div>
   <div class="clear"></div></div></div><!--end footer -->




   </body>
   </html>
```

CSS:

```
    /*footer */
    #footer3 {padding:36px 0px; background: url(/images/common/footer/footer-black.png); background-repeat:text-align:left; width: auto; font-size:14px; font-weight:normal;}
    #footer3-contents { margin:10px; width: auto; padding-left: 95px;}
    #footer3 h2 { color:#fff;  font-size:12px; padding-left:0px; }
    #footer3 h2 a { color:#fff; }
    #footer3 a { color:#fff; }
    #footer3 #footer-legal ul { padding: 0px; margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;}
    #footer3 #footer-legal ul li {float:left; padding: 10px 10px 2px 0px;}
    #icons {padding-right:4px;}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: It's not your footer, it's the footer contents. Adjust #footer3-contents { margin:10px; width: auto; padding-left: 95px;} till you are happy with the result

Answer (score 1):

```
#footer3-contents {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
}
```

Change #footer3-contents to the above and it will work.

The reason this issue is happening is because all your doing is pushing the footer over 95px in your original code. What you need to do is set a defined width for the footer contents then set the margins on each side to be equal.

If the margins are equal on both sides the div will appear in the center of your webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Provide margin value in % rather than px.